# Rails + SQL Server + Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, macos

Alright. While there are a few blog posts here and there purporting to make this process easy, this is absolutely driving me crazy.

Here's what I've done:

- I've installed FreeTDS (with and without +mssql) but encounter problems when I use it to connect to my remote DB instance. When I attempt

  tsql -H [remote-db-ip] -p 1433 -U [valid-username]

  I am informed (after a minute or so) that Tsql was unable to connect, because Adaptive Server is unavailable or doesn't exist.
- Installed the Actual driver. Created a user-level DSN through ODBC administrator which "successfully" connects to my remote SQL server (even acquiring correct DB version.) However, when I try to test it through iODBC it says:

  [Actual][SQL Server] Unable to connect to data source (0) SQLSTATE=08001
- Installed DBI (0.4.1) and DBD:ODBC (0.2.4) gems. Encounter the same error if I try to connect through irb.
- Installed rails-sqlserver-2000-2005-adapter (2.2.19). Checked out my Rails application and ran script/server. Setup my database.yml to the same values that work to remote connect on my windows development machine. Appears to startup alright, but I encountered the same error when I try to navigate to the app's homepage.

Thanks, and please let me know if I've left some extremely obvious step! This is killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others may find [this documentation](http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/) more to their liking, as it's a bit less Unix-y and a bit more Mac-ish.

Answer (score 2):

I've used these directions in the past and it's working flawlessly - give it a shot and let me know where you get hung up: http://toolmantim.com/articles/getting_rails_talking_to_sqlserver_on_osx_via_odbc

You certainly need FreeTDS if you haven't installed it yet.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've installed FreeTDS (with and without +mssql) but encounter problems when I use it to connect to my remote DB instance. When I attempt tsql -H <remote_db_ip> -p 1433 -U <valid_username> I am informed (after a minute or so) that Tsql was unable to connect, because Adaptive Server is unavailable or doesn't exist. Note that I'm successfully connecting -- even acquiring the correct database version -- when I run the configuration tests on the DSN through ODBC administrator using the Actual driver...

Comment: Hmm. One other thing: 

In order to actually connect to my SQL box, I need to run:

TDSVER=7.0 tsql -H [hostname] -p 1433 -U [user] -P [pass]

with the environment variable I get:

Unexpected EOF from the server
Msg 20002, Level 9, State -1, Server OpenClient, Line -1
Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server

Comment: Doesn't seem to help (tried versions 6 and 8 as well)...

Comment: Bummer. And if you telnet to the host on port 1433, you resolve it and connect with no problem?

Comment: That was it, some network settings on the server which needed to be cleaned up...

Thanks!

Comment: The link above is now broken. Does anyone have a link to a similar tutorial?

Comment: Matt, you may find this suits you -- http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/